# Parametrising index of array in Selenium IDE

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-ide

I have an array and a variable storing a number.

I can access the array like so:

```
${arr[1]}
```

But what I want to achieve is to access a specific index with a parameter, i.e.:

```
${arr[${parameter}]}
```

It does not work and just outputs it verbatim.

In the end, what I want to achieve is a loop through the array of 30 elements.
Then type something in the first 3 elements, then type something else in the next 3, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

Nevermind.
This works:

```
${arr}[${parameter}]
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **For Each** command to handle it.

For each iteration, you will get an element of the array.

```
execute script | return new array("element1", "element2") | array1
For each | array1 | iterator
  echo | ${iterator}
End
```

The output:

```
element1
element2
```