# How do I put a variable in the parameters of an array

Tags: selenium-ide

I want to put variable in the parameters to specify element of an array by doing this:

```
${array[${index}]}
```

but, it just prints the whole text.

Input:

```
${array[${index}]}
```

Output:

```
"${array[${index}]}"
```

Edit:

So here is an example:

```
execute script | return ["first", "second"] | array
```

execute script | return 1 | index

```
Input:
```

type| id="inputbox"| ${array}[${index}]

```
Expected output:
```

"second"

```
Real Output:
```

"first,second[1]"

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parametrising index of array in Selenium IDE](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68907274/parametrising-index-of-array-in-selenium-ide)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the correct syntax for putting an index variable as a parameter to the array? Is this what you want to accomplish:

```py
${array}[${index}]
```

Here is an example of how to get access the array element by index:

[image]

Comment: Ive tried that but it outputs everything in the array plus the index number like this:
"First, Second[1]" instead of just "First"

Comment: I'm not sure whether that is the output you should be getting for this input. Can you provide a clear input/output example by printing this: ${array}[${index}]?

Comment: So here is an example: 

execute script | return ["first", "second"] | array
execute script | return 1 | index

Input:
type| id="inputbox"| ${array}[${index}]

Expected output:
"second"

Real Output:
"first,second[1]"

Comment: I see what you are doing here. You have to store its return value onto a variable, otherwise it will process it as a string: ${array} would first render as first,second and ${index} would render as [1], that is why you are getting concatenation of these two. See updated example image to get how to get the actual prop value.

Comment: It never occurred to me to do it like that, it worked! thank you!